# Without using jquery, how to cycle through images to make a simple slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

You have a div, with 3 images in it.

How to create a simple slideshow that cycles through the images, and displays each image for 5 seconds and goes back to the first image when done and continues looping.

**Without using jquery or any other framework.**

Comment: Might I inquire into why you'd want to make more work for yourself?

Comment: just to learn, to dependent on jQ

Answer (score 4):

```
(function () {
    var imgs = document.getElementById('your_div').getElementsByTagName('img'),
        index = 0;
    imgs[0].style.display = 'block';
    setInterval(function () {
        imgs[index].style.display = 'none';
        index = (index + 1) % imgs.length;
        imgs[index].style.display = 'block';
    }, 5000);
}());
```

Example HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/Zq7KB/1/

**Edit**: Saw a more elegant example above that used .length.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to set up the timed callback, and set the `src` of an `img` element:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var slides = [ "path_to_image_one",
                   "path_to_image_two",
                   "path_to_image_three" // ...
                 ],
        index = 0,
        timer = 0;

    // Show the first slide
    showNextSlide();

    // Show "next" slide every five seconds
    timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 5000);

    // The function we call to show the "next" slide    
    function showNextSlide() {
        if (index >= slides.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('theImage').src = slides[index++];
    }
};
```

...where your markup for the image is:

```
<img id="theImage" src="path_to_initial_placeholder">
```

Note that I've stored the timer handle in `timer` but not used it. This is just because you might use it to cancel the timer if you need to stop the slideshow.

**Update**: Just saw that you want to get the images from a div somewhere (whereas above I've supplied the paths in the code itself). Simple enough to create `slides` dynamically; revised edition of the above that grabs the images that are *direct* children of the div with the ID "theDiv":

```
window.onload = function() {
    var slides = [],
        index = 0,
        timer = 0,
        node;

    // Get the slides
    for (node = document.getElementById('theDiv').childNodes;
         node;
         node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == "IMG") {
            slides.push(node.src);
        }
    }

    // Show the first slide
    showNextSlide();

    // Show "next" slide every five seconds
    timer = setInterval(showNextSlide, 5000);

    // The function we call to show the "next" slide    
    function showNextSlide() {
        if (index >= slides.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('theImage').src = slides[index++];
    }
};
```

Comment: I should just follow-up and say: It's really well worth using a library for this stuff. I know you said you don't want to, so the answer sticks with that, but a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can really factor out a lot of common stuff and let you concentrate on your actual goals.

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd have to get a handle for the `<div>` first, so if it has an "id" value:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
```

Now you just have to set up a timer to cycle through the images:

```
(function(div, sleep) {
  var idx = 0;
  var imgs = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
  function showOne() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i)
      imgs[i].style.display = 'none';
    imgs[idx].style.display = '';
    idx = (idx + 1) % imgs.length;
    setTimeout(showOne, sleep);
  }

  showOne();
})(theDiv, 5000);
```

Comment: Of course, getElementsByTagName is not portable to older browsers, which is why jQuery is so popular.  But it's fine with IE6 and up, which ought to rate as 'good enough' nowadays.

Comment: It horrifies me to contemplate included IE5.5 in the planning of new applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = new Array('/img/1.jpg', '/img/2.jpg', '/img/3.jpg');

setTimeout("show_next()",5000);

function show_next()
{
var container = document.getElementById('image_container');
container.innerHTML = "<img src='" + image[i] + "' />";
if(i==2) { i = 1; }else { i = i + 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a nice simple answer, but there were a couple of errors.
`setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` and the initial index was not set.  I also amended to load first image immediately.

```
var image = new Array('imgs/18/P1050294-XL.jpg', 'imgs/18/P1050293-XL.jpg', 'imgs/18/P1040984-XL.jpg', 'imgs/18/P1040983-XL.jpg', 'imgs/18/P1040982-XL.jpg');

var path = 'mypath';

document.getElementById('slideShow').innerHTML = "<img width='600px' src='" + path + image[0] + "' />"  // Load First image
var i = 1;  // Set counter to second image, for first use of loop

setInterval("show_next(path)",5000);

function show_next(path)
{
var container = document.getElementById('slideShow');
container.innerHTML = "<img width='600px' src='" + path + image[i] + "' />";
if(i==4) { i = 0; } else { i = i + 1; }
}
```

Comment: I was replying to the answer below, but got it in the wrong position - apologies.